# How to wrap a function which contains hooks with HoC

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hoc

As the title suggest I want to be able to wrap a function (which contains) hooks in a HoC.

In the example below I want to be able to wrap the JSX from `TestView` with `div` element tag where the `className="someClassName"`. However I get the following exception:

> Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
>   This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See  for tips about how to debug and
>   fix this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

function wrap(component) {
    let calledComponent = component()
    return (
        <div className="someClassName">
          {calledComponent}
        </div>
    );
  }


function TestView() {
    const [ val, setValue] = React.useState('Initial Value');
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={val} onChange={event=>setValue(event.target.value)}/>
        </div>
    )

 }

 export default wrap(TestView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Concretely, a higher-order component is a function that takes a
>   component and returns a new component.
>   [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

so, you have to have a function that returns a component, maybe like this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../styles.css';

const withStyle = WrappedComponent => {
  return function WithStyle() {
    return (
      <div className='myClassStyle'>
        <WrappedComponent />
      </div>
    );
  };
};

function TestView() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState('Initial Value');
  return (
    <div>
      <input type='text' value={val} onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyle(TestView);
```